# Git diff - how to get different files (only name) between two tags by 'git diff' and order by the file commit time

Tags: git, git-diff

Through the command:

```
$git diff --name-status tag1 tag2 -- target-src
```

The output is like:

```
M       src/config.h
M       src/createTable.sql
A       src/gameserver/BattleGround_10v10.h
M       src/gameserver/CMakeLists.txt
M       src/gameserver/achieve.cpp
M       src/gameserver/achieve.h
A       src/gameserver/action.cpp
A       src/gameserver/action.h
A       src/gameserver/activity.cpp
A       src/gameserver/activity.h
M       src/gameserver/admin.cpp
```

I got the files that has modified between the two tags. But I want the list order by committed time. How can I do that?

---

Thanks to [ilius's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18400336/git-diff-how-to-get-different-files-only-name-between-two-tags-by-git-diff/18401074#18401074), I added `awk` for my request:

```
git diff --name-status tag1 tag2 | while read line ; do
    status=${line:0:1}
    path=${line:2}
    date=$(git log -1 '--pretty=format:%ci' -- "$path")
    echo "$date    $status   $path"
done | sort -r | awk '{print $4" "$5}'
```

But I think it is too complicated. Can it be simpler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [mart1n's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18400336/git-diff-how-to-get-different-files-only-name-between-two-tags-by-git-diff/18400483#18400483),

```
git log --name-status '--pretty=format:' tag1 tag2 -- target-src | grep -vxh '\s*'
```

gives a clean output.

Also try this script:

```
git diff --name-status tag1 tag2 | while read line ; do
    status=${line:0:1}
    path=${line:2}
    date=$(git log -1 '--pretty=format:%ci' -- "$path")
    echo "$date    $status   $path"
done | sort -r
```

You can remove the dates (used for sorting) later, I think dates are useful though.

You can also remove `-r` option from `sort` if you want the older changed files to be on top.

Comment: what I want is the different file between two tag, not the modify log.It is the difference;

Comment: I added a script, check it out

Answer (score 0):

You can try the same thing, but with `git log`:

```
git log --name-status tag1 tag2 -- target-src
```

That way, the files are sorted in the order the commits were made. Also `git log` has various sorting options you can try out.